# Glass Mapper exception : Can not convert value PermanentRedirect to enum type

Tags: enums, sitecore, aero-glass, glass-mapper

I am getting glass mapper exception in my project solution as follow

```
stack trace:
[MapperException: Can not convert value PermanentRedirect to enum type IELTS.Web.IELTS.Models.Redirections.StatusCodes]
Glass.Mapper.Sc.DataMappers.SitecoreFieldEnumMapper.GetFieldValue(String fieldValue, SitecoreFieldConfiguration config, SitecoreDataMappingContext context) +280
Glass.Mapper.Sc.DataMappers.AbstractSitecoreFieldMapper.GetField(Field field, SitecoreFieldConfiguration config, SitecoreDataMappingContext context) +124

[MapperException: Failed to map field Type with value PermanentRedirect]
Glass.Mapper.Sc.DataMappers.AbstractSitecoreFieldMapper.GetField(Field field, SitecoreFieldConfiguration config, SitecoreDataMappingContext context) +326
Glass.Mapper.AbstractDataMapper.MapCmsToProperty(AbstractDataMappingContext mappingContext) +29
Glass.Mapper.Configuration.AbstractTypeConfiguration.MapPropertiesToObject(Object obj, IAbstractService service, AbstractTypeCreationContext context) +158

[MapperException: Failed to map property Type on IELTS.Web.IELTS.Models.Redirections.Redirection]
Glass.Mapper.Configuration.AbstractTypeConfiguration.MapPropertiesToObject(Object obj, IAbstractService service, AbstractTypeCreationContext context) +488
Glass.Mapper.Pipelines.ObjectConstruction.Tasks.CreateConcrete.CreateConcreteTask.CreateObject(ObjectConstructionArgs args) +295
Glass.Mapper.Pipelines.ObjectConstruction.Tasks.CreateConcrete.CreateConcreteTask.Execute(ObjectConstructionArgs args) +215
Glass.Mapper.Pipelines.AbstractPipelineRunner`2.Run(T args) +225
Glass.Mapper.AbstractService.InstantiateObject(AbstractTypeCreationContext abstractTypeCreationContext) +170
Glass.Mapper.Sc.SitecoreService.CreateType(Type type, Item item, Boolean isLazy, Boolean inferType, Object[] constructorParameters) +265
Glass.Mapper.Sc.SitecoreService.CreateType(Item item, Boolean isLazy, Boolean inferType) +109
Glass.Mapper.Sc.SitecoreContext.GetCurrentItem(Boolean isLazy, Boolean inferType) +90

IELTS.Web.IELTS.Controllers.RedirectionController.Redirect() in c:\IDPNow\Trunk\src\IELTS.Web\IELTS\Controllers\RedirectionController.cs:15
lambda_method(Closure , ControllerBase , Object[] ) +79

System.Web.Mvc.ReflectedActionDescriptor.Execute(ControllerContext controllerContext, IDictionary`2 parameters) +261
System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionMethod(ControllerContext controllerContext, ActionDescriptor actionDescriptor, IDictionary`2 parameters) +39
System.Web.Mvc.<>c__DisplayClass15.<InvokeActionMethodWithFilters>b__12() +124
System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionMethodFilter(IActionFilter filter, ActionExecutingContext preContext, Func`1 continuation) +681242
System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionMethodFilter(IActionFilter filter, ActionExecutingContext preContext, Func`1 continuation) +681242
System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionMethodWithFilters(ControllerContext controllerContext, IList`1 filters, ActionDescriptor actionDescriptor, IDictionary`2 parameters) +307
System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeAction(ControllerContext controllerContext, String actionName) +345
```

My rendering class looks like below,

```
 public class Redirection : RenderingModel
    {
        [SitecoreField("Destination")]
        public virtual Glass.Mapper.Sc.Fields.Link Destination { get; set; }

        [SitecoreField("Type")]
        public virtual StatusCodes Type { get; set; }
    }

    public enum StatusCodes
    {
        Permanent = 301,
        Temporary = 302
    }
```

my controller method looks like,

```
public ActionResult Redirect()
        {
            var context = new SitecoreContext(IdpTemplates.CurrentContext);

            var redirection = context.GetCurrentItem<Redirection>();

            return new RedirectResult(redirection.Destination.Url, Convert.ToInt32(redirection.Type) == 301);
        }
```

in above method I am getting exception at             var redirection = context.GetCurrentItem(); line.

Comment: Welcome stackoverflow..! Actually, you should post some piece of code that cause error. So, we can think what should be error. Now, you just post your error log. We cannot find error, just seeing log. We need to know code. Okay..! So [edit](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/31529878/edit) your post by adding some code what you tried.

Answer (score 0):

Your fieldvalue contains 'PermanentRedirect' but  your enum does not have that value. It has: 'Permanent' and 'Temporary'.

The names must have an exact match (case sensitive). Maybe you changed it at a certain point in time? Or maybe you have a wrong default value?